# Extracting the change of the mean per group over time

Tags: r, mean

I have a data table from which I calculated the mean `sales` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"ID country year sales industry size cat4
1   NLD   2000  4   A   1   0
2   NLD   2000  4   B   1   1
3   NLD   2006  2   A   1   1
4   NLD   2002  4   A   1   0
5   NLD   2002  4   B   1   1
6   NLD   2006  2   A   1   1
7   NLD   2006  2   B   2   0
8   NLD   2006  1   A   1   4
9   GBR   2001  2   B   3   5
10  GBR   2001  1   B   2   5
11  GBR   2002  1   A   1   11
12  GBR   2006  1   A   1   2
13  GBR   2006  1   B   3   12
14  GBR   2006  1   A   1   2
15  GBR   2006  1   B   3   12",
header = TRUE)

setDT(DT)[,Mean_Sales:= mean(sales, na.rm=TRUE),  by=c("country", "industry", "size")]
```

However, now I am interested in how `Mean_Sales` changes over time, per group: `by=c("iso3c", "industry", "size")`.

I would like to take the `mean of the absolute differences`, divided by the years they are apart.

As an example, for a company in NLD of industry A and size 1, constituting to `ID`=1 and `ID`=8, I want the mean of absolute differences (`|1-4|=3`), divided by the years apart (`2006-2000 = 6`). Leading to a year to year change of the mean of `3/6 = 0.5`.

I just cannot figure out how to get it into R code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Desired output:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"ID country year sales industry size cat4 delta
1   NLD   2000  4   A   1   0   0.5
2   NLD   2000  4   B   1   1   0.33
3   NLD   2006  2   A   1   1
4   NLD   2002  4   A   1   0
5   NLD   2002  4   B   1   1
6   NLD   2006  2   A   1   1
7   NLD   2006  2   B   1   0   0.33
8   NLD   2006  1   A   1   4   0.5
9   GBR   2001  2   B   3   5
10  GBR   2001  1   B   2   5
11  GBR   2002  1   A   1   11
12  GBR   2006  1   A   1   2
13  GBR   2006  1   B   3   12
14  GBR   2006  1   A   1   2
15  GBR   2006  1   B   3   12",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `order` by `year` and get absolute difference between `last` and `first` `sales` value and divide it by difference in `year`.

```
library(data.table)

DT[order(year), delta := abs(last(sales) - first(sales))/(max(year) - min(year)), 
               .(country, industry, size)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ronak. Do you perhaps mean `Mean_Sales` instead of `sales`?

Comment: @Tom I think the example calculation you shared was with reference to `sales` and not `mean_sales` ( `|1-4|=3`) ?

Comment: I think I should have created a better example haha. Anyway, I think it should still work by applying your solution to `Mean_Sales`.

Comment: Does that work? Does it give you the expected output?

Comment: Hey Ronak,I think I will remove this question. The code technically works, but because I made some errors thinking the question through, it does not do what I want. I will post a new, better formulated, question. Thank you very much for your help though!